# newline in RegEx search in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How do I search for a newline character in the Chrome developer tools so that I can search for a text that spans multiple lines?

I've tried [\r\n]+ but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this cannot be done because the Web Inspector breaks up the code on the line breaks before performing the regex test.

[image: Regex functionality]